# Two letter initials in bibliography

Tags: bibtex

I have the following `author` field in a `bibtex` file:

```
author = "Lastname, Theo and Surname, Sam"
```

In the reference list, when using a style that applies initials, I want it to print:

```
Th. Lastname and S. Surname
```

instead of

```
T. Lastname and S. Surname
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  See [Tame the BeaST](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast) section 13.1, i.e. write `{\relax Th}eo` in the `bib` file.

Comment: @AndrewSwann -- although i'm sure i've seen this before, couldn't find a duplicate.  make this an answer, please, and post an entry in the "often referenced questions" -- it's sure to come up again.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained rather well in the document [TameTheBeast](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tamethebeast).  The solution is to write `Theo` as

```
{\relax Th}eo
```

in the bibliography file.  This way `{\relax Th}` is treated as a single special character by the bibtex processor and in particular it is not shortened to just `T` when creating the abbreviation.  A "special character" is any group `{\...}` at the top level within in an entry with first character a backslash `\`.  The main use of this is for accented characters.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{myart,
  author = {Lastname, {\relax Th}eo and Surname, Sam},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {J. Jour.},
  year = 1983,
  volume = 27,
  number = 2,
  pages = {31--38}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{myart}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfect! Also thank you for the very helpful document you cited!